# Map Control Genexus no funciona Style

Tags: web, genexus

Intento modificar el aspecto del Map Control de Genexus, modificando la propiedad **Style** con diversos valores, el que me interesa es Retro, pero no se modifica.
He intentado modificarlo en el editor del control y en el evento start.
GeneXus 17 U11. Java

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: De verdad? Si alguien no lo entiende, es que no conoce GeneXus, y si no conoce la herramienta, no creo que me valga su respuesta.